# Displaying a message after specific text is inputed

Tags: javascript, html

I need to make an input box that displays text (for example, help). If the said person types help and hits the button I create after I would like a message to display saying GOOD, if the person types anything other then (help) I need it to say WRONG.

I'm trying really hard and just can not get it.

Here is what I have so far.

Javascript:

```
function password(){
    if(document.getElementById("good").value == "GOOD"){

    }else(document.getElementById("wrong").value == "WRONG"){

    }  
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="help" value="help" required>
```

Verify

Sorry in advance if it's awful, I'm very new to this.

THANK YOU!

Comment: Checkout my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please edit your code as below.

```js
document.getElementById("buttonSubmit").addEventListener("click", submit);

function submit(){
   let inputVal =  document.getElementById("help").value.toLowerCase();
 
   if(inputVal == 'help'){
     console.log('GOOD'); 
   }else{
     console.log('WRONG');
   }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="help" value="help" required>
<button id="buttonSubmit">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use an object instead of long "if" chains, if you are going to add multiple commands.

https://javascript.info/ → see "Conditional operators", "Objects"

```js
let obj = {
  help: "Helpicus",
  foo: "bar!",
  moo: "cow!",
};

let input  = document.getElementById('input');
let demo = document.getElementById('demo');
let ok   = document.getElementById('ok');

ok.addEventListener('click', function(){
  let key = input.value.toLowerCase().trim();
  
  demo.textContent = ( obj[key] ? obj[key] : "Wrong Command!" );
});
```

```html
<input id="input">
<button id="ok">ok</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```